# Calling func(didSelectItemAt) while UIcollectionview is on scrolling

Tags: swift, scroll, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Currently I'm using `UICollectionView` with several cells in it.  `UICollectionView` scrolls horizontally to move between the cells.
My question is : **Is there any way to call func(didSelectItemAt) by clicking the cell *while its `UICollectionView` is on scrolling*?**

Here is gif.

[image]

Right after dragging cell to left for scrolling, I click the cell continuously to call func(didSelectItemAt) but it get call only when scrolling is finished. **Is it possible to func(didSelectItemAt) to be called instantly right after clicking cell while on scrolling?**

Here is my code for collectionView delegate & dataSource.

```
extension CardViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {
public func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cardCount
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = cardCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "card", for: indexPath) as! CardCell
    cell.isFront = cellsSelectedStatus[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = cardCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CardCell
    UIView.transition(with: cell, duration: 0.3, options: [.transitionFlipFromLeft,.allowUserInteraction], animations: nil, completion: nil)
    cellsSelectedStatus[indexPath.row] = !(cellsSelectedStatus[indexPath.row])
    cell.isFront = cellsSelectedStatus[indexPath.row]

    print("did select")

}
```

Collectionview’s dataSource&delegate are called in `viewDidLoad`.

I know there is `allowUserInteraction` from `UIViewAnimationOptions` which allows to click view while its being animated. Is there smilier code for func(didSelectItemAt)?

There’s no networking & UIGestureRecognizers is attached to the cell or collectionview.
So far I've set
`isUserInteractionEnabled`,
`isMultipleTouchEnabled`,
`allowsMultipleSelection` to true for collectionView,
but it still behaves the same. 
I’m using Swift3, Xcode9.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add code in text format, not an image.

Comment: Just fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: You can ans your question for others' help.

Comment: Oh i meant fixing the code image to text format. I  havent solved my question yet.

Comment: From the gif it seems you're using a custom uicollectionview flow layout, so my guess will be clicking on the cell is disabled within the custom flow class. Do you have a snippet of that code?

Comment: Ive tried with a just normal UICollectionView without any custom flow, it behaved the same. I assumed UICollectionView has a problem itself.  However Ill post snippet of that code soon.